# Warning: The type TestNG is deprecated

Tags: selenium, testng

I am trying to make a starting point class which will generate a `testng.xml` which will in turn start all the testcases.

```
package trigger;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import com.beust.testng.TestNG;

public class StartTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        XmlSuite suite1 = new XmlSuite();
        suite1.setName("S1");

        XmlTest t1 = new XmlTest(suite1);
        t1.setName("Test1");

        XmlClass c1 = new XmlClass("testcases.TC_MMI_001");
        XmlClass c2 = new XmlClass("testcases.TC_MMI_002");
        XmlClass c3 = new XmlClass("testcases.TC_MMI_003");

        ArrayList<XmlClass> ac =  new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
        ac.add(c1);
        ac.add(c2);
        ac.add(c3);
        t1.setXmlClasses(ac);

        ArrayList<XmlTest> at= new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
        at.add(t1);
        suite1.setTests(at);

        ArrayList<XmlSuite> as = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
        as.add(suite1);

        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        tng.setXmlSuites(as);
        tng.run();
    }

}
```

Is there a another way of doing this without getting the deprecated warning in `TestNG`?

Comment: You should be using the TestNG class from the package org.testng.TestNG. Just replace the package import statement.

Comment: Works. Appreciate it 